# How can I return file creation date?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How can I get the file creation date in C ?  I see the function `getFileTime` but I don't know how can I use it to return creation time:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetFileTime(

__in       HANDLE hFile,                // handle to the file
__out_opt  LPFILETIME lpCreationTime,   // FILETIME struct for creation    time
__out_opt  LPFILETIME lpLastAccessTime, // FILETIME struct for last access time
__out_opt  LPFILETIME lpLastWriteTime   // FILETIME struct for last modification time
 );
```

//I do this one but d'ont work it return  01/01/1601 . I need to do date creation not date modification

```
 HANDLE h_fichier;
 LPCWSTR fname = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IE tn-Sign\\tn-Sign-plugin- ie.dll";
 FILETIME date_fichier_tmp;
 SYSTEMTIME date_fichier_utc, date_fichier_local;
//Ouverture du fichier
h_fichier =       CreateFile(fname,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
if(h_fichier == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    printf("CreateFile ko %S\n", fname);
EstEID_log("CreateFile ko %S\n", fname);
//Date de modification du fichier
if (!GetFileTime(h_fichier, NULL, NULL, &date_fichier_tmp))
    printf("GetFileTime ko\n");
EstEID_log("GetFileTime ko\n");
//Convertion de la date
FileTimeToSystemTime(&date_fichier_tmp, &date_fichier_utc);
SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &date_fichier_utc, &date_fichier_local);
printf("Derniere modification le %02d-%02d-%d %02dh%02d\n", date_fichier_local.wDay, date_fichier_local.wMonth, date_fichier_local.wYear, date_fichier_local.wHour, date_fichier_local.wMinute);

EstEID_log("Derniere modification le %02d-%02d-%d %02dh%02d\n", date_fichier_local.wDay, date_fichier_local.wMonth, date_fichier_local.wYear, date_fichier_local.wHour, date_fichier_local.wMinute);
//Fermeture du fichier
CloseHandle(h_fichier);
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `GetFileTime()` API returns the creation, modification, and access times of a file, subject to the support of the file system and operating system handling of each kind of time/date. Per [GetFileTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, the create time is the first parameter (after the file handle). Your existing call is retrieving the "last write time" (aka, modified time). Instead change the parameter to to return

```
… GetFileTime(h_fichier, &date_fichier_tmp, NULL, NULL) …
```

Comment: it return  01/01/1601  how can I convert it to correct date

Comment: It sounds like `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` is failing. You should check the return values of that and `FileTimeToSystemTime()`. You should output the value of `date_fichier_utc` to see what the UTC time is (it should only be a few hours from your local time). Is the Modified Time that your example shows, returning a "reasonable" date value?

Comment: Have you checked that both the other functions completed without error? You may need to specify the locale parameter explicitly... perhaps your system's setting is messed up.

Comment: date_fichier_utc  return the same thing  I do like this :                                                               FileTimeToSystemTime(&date_fichier_tmp, &date_fichier_utc);
 //SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &date_fichier_utc, &date_fichier_local);

 EstEID_log("Date de creation le %02d-%02d-%d %02dh%02d\n", date_fichier_utc.wDay, date_fichier_utc.wMonth, date_fichier_utc.wYear, date_fichier_utc.wHour, date_fichier_utc.wMinute);
the output : Date de creation le 11-01-1601 00h45

Comment: It looks like your UTC and locale dates differ by 10 days! I did not know that would even be possible. I would try each of the following: (0) Check that your system time and timezone are setting correctly; (1) Check return values of each function to ensure that all of them succeed (is `GetFileTime()` succeeding? (2) Check what Windows says the file's date/times are (get file properties to see them)

Comment: how can I know if the if (is GetFileTime() succeed or NO

Comment: As with many of the API functions, if the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError()`

Comment: What does the shell report for the actual file creation time? Are you positive that you're getting the wrong answer?